# Django query based on FK — get all, not any

Tags: python, mysql, django

I need to find an order with all order items with status = completed. It looks like this:

```
FINISHED_STATUSES = [17,18,19]
if active_tab == 'outstanding':
    orders = orders.exclude(items__status__in=FINISHED_STATUSES)
```

However, this query only gives me orders with **any** order item with a completed status. How would I do the query such that I retrieve only those orders with **ALL** order items with a completed status?

Comment: I'm not sure why someone voted to close this question. I think it has merit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this done by a sort of hackish way. First, I added an additional Boolean column, `is_finished`. Then, to find an order with at least one non-finished item:

```
orders = orders.filter(items__status__is_finished=False)
```

This gives me all un-finished orders.

Doing the opposite of that gets the finished orders:

```
orders = orders.exclude(items__status__is_finished=False)
```

Comment: That's probably the best way to solve your problem.  I wouldn't consider it hackish - I would consider it refactoring your design.  If you run into a similar situation in the future, check out my revised answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you need to do raw query here:

Set you orders and items model as Orders and Items:

```
# raw query
sql = """\
  select `orders`.* from `%{orders_table}s` as `orders`
  join `%{items_table}s` as `items`
  on `items`.`%{item_order_fk}s` = `orders`.`%{order_pk}s`
  where `items`.`%{status_field}s` in (%{status_list}s)
  group by `orders`.`%{orders_pk}s`
  having count(*) = %{status_count)s;
""" % {
        "orders_table": Orders._meta.db_table,
        "items_table":  Items._meta.db_table,
        "order_pk":     Orders._meta.pk.colum,
        "item_order_fk":Items._meta.get_field("order").colum,
        "status_field": Items._meta.get_field("status").colum,
        "status_list":  str(FINISHED_STATUSES)[1:-1],
        "status_count": len(FINISHED_STATUSES),
    }

orders = Orders.objects.raw(sql)
```

Comment: Good answer, as Django ORM doesn't support group by.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the boolean field is a good idea.  That way you have your business rules clearly defined in the model.

Now, let's say that you still wanted to do it without resorting to adding fields.  This may very well be a requirement given a different set of circumstances.  Unfortunately, you can't really use subqueries or arbitrary joins in the Django ORM.  You could, however, build up `Q` objects and make an implicit join in the having clause using `filter()` and `annotate()`.

```py
from django.db.models.aggregates import Count
from django.db.models import Q
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_

total_items_by_orders = Orders.objects.annotate(
    item_count=Count('items'))
finished_items_by_orders = Orders.objects.filter(
    items__status__in=FINISHED_STATUSES).annotate(
    item_count=Count('items'))
orders = total_items_by_orders.exclude(
    reduce(or_, (Q(id=o.id, item_count=o.item_count)
                 for o in finished_items_by_orders)))
```

Note that using raw SQL, while less elegant, would usually be more efficient.